# Not able to use css only for IE browser

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

i want to apply css only for the IE browser, when i browsed through the net, i got a approach which worked for many of the people but i am not able to acheive the same for IE browser using that code. below is my code

```
<!--[if IE]>
<style>
  div{
    border:solid 5px yellow;
    }
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

what am i doing wrong? i am using IE11.

**note:** i am using this code in the HTML, but still it is not working

**UPDATE**

i also tried this but it is not working for IE11

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {  
   /* Put your IE-only styles here. Works for IS 10 & IE 11*/
}
```

Comment: conditional comments are not supported in IE 10+

Comment: but what about media query, it should work, am i right?

Comment: Yes, it should work., What's more, it DOES work. https://plnkr.co/edit/3haWNAZL8jWRJjUPUE2l?p=preview